# Swift strings are not being stored in struct

Tags: swift, memory, swift3

I have a bare bones struct.

```
struct Transaction {
    var value: String = ""
    var date: String = ""
    var title: String = ""
}
```

In my project, `Transaction` is used like so...

```
var transaction:Transaction = Transaction()
//loops 3 times
repeat {
    let parsed = stringAndType(from:myParser)//-> (string:String, type:UInt8)
    switch parsed.type {
    case 1:
        print("1 -- \(parsed.string")
        transaction.value = parsed.string
    case 2:
        print("2 -- \(parsed.string)")
        transaction.date = parsed.string
    case 4:
        print("4 -- \(parsed.string)")
        transaction.title = parsed.string
    default: break
    }
} while myParser.isOk
print("Returning transaction: \(transaction)")
return transaction
```

In this code, a structure is created. The parser feeds the data to the switch, which assigns the parsed string to the appropriate `Transaction` variable. When I run the following code, the output indicates that the assignments to `transaction.date` and `transaction.value` are not sticking.

Output:

```
2 -- 12/22/2015
1 -- -5.00
4 -- RECURRING PAYMENT BACKBLAZE
Returning transaction: Transaction(value: "", date: "", title: "RECURRING PAYMENT BACKBLAZE")
```

There is complex buffering behind the scenes in `stringAndType()`. Looking at this as a C programmer, I really want to think that function might be the problem. However, I was under the impression that Swift strings are structures, and are therefore copy on write, just like an integer or double. Hoping you can provide insight. Thank you for your time.

**Update 02/15/17**

The logic in this code is functioning as expected. I think the problem here is memory management. To help drive this point, I've...

1. Removed the `print` lines from my switch
2. Added `didSet {}` to each variable in `Transaction`

Like so...

```
struct Transaction {
    var value: String = "" {
        didSet {
            print("The VALUE has changed from \(oldValue) to \(value)")
        }
    }
    //this is repeated appropriately for the other two variables
}
```

The given output rules out any logical issues. Output:

```
The DATE has changed from  to 12/22/2015
The VALUE has changed from  to -5.00
The TITLE has changed from  to RECURRING PAYMENT BACKBLAZE
Returning transaction: Transaction(value: "", date: "", title: "RECURRING PAYMENT BACKBLAZE")
```

`stringAndType()` does **read** from an unsafe buffer, **but it copies the bytes to a `Data` structure, and returns a string initialized from the COPIED data**. I thought this would insulate me from safety issues...perhaps theres an implementation detail to `String` I'm missing?

Comment: I believe that it's entering the switch case and is going to the last case where the title is being assigned and not the `value` and `date`.

Comment: Why do you think, that you switch case will fall through case 1? It looks like it never executes other cases.

Comment: When I try running your code using an array with string values, everything works fine: Returning transaction: Transaction(value: "12/22/2015", date: "-5.00", title: "RECURRING PAYMENT BACKBLAZE")

Comment: What is the scope of your function `stringAndType`? Is it local? I.E. in the same scope as the declaration of `transaction`?

Comment: @Grimxn yes, same scope. `stringAndType()` is a fileprivate func in `csv.swift`, `Transaction` is the first declaration in the same file.

Comment: Any chance there is a namespace collision? Do you use anything called `transaction` in the function? As @unkgd says, the code as shown works fine replacing the function with an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @unkgd, you were on the right track with your initial answer before you retracted it. There was a logical error between the `while parser.isOk` loop and the parent loop (omitted to keep the code short) that was wiping Transaction between `value` and `title` being set. There was no indication of this happening in the output. The loop posted above was not looping three times, rather, it was looping once, but that single loop was iterated three times by the parent. Therefore, only the most recent parsed value was stored in the structure, in this case, `title`. Again, full credit to @unkgd (if you repost your answer and I will mark it as correct). Thanks to everyone for their ideas.